# How to add html to tab upload of image plugin ckeditor 4

Tags: ckeditor

[How to add html to tab upload of image plugin ckeditor 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLPju.jpg)

How to add input html to tab upload in ckeditor 4?

Comment: and how to get value of it, thanks for reply.

Comment: If it is not possible. How it run javascript: "alert('Please attention to Watermark')" ( event listern ) when press button image or tab upload inside it.
Thanks for reply.